# Combining two graphs with different x axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to combine a bar chart and line chart by using ggplot. The problem is, the x axis of bar chart is shop names while the x axis of line chart is date. Graphs look like this:

[image]

[image]

```
g1 <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=shop, y=conversion_rate)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) 

g2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(plot_data_mean, mapping = aes(x=date, y=conversion_rate_average))
```

Is there a way to combine these two graphs?

Comment: Can you post your data using `dput()`?

Comment: I've found the `patchwork` package particular well-tuned for requests like this. Try: `library(patchwork)`, then either `g1 + g2` for side-by-side or `g1 / g2` for top/bottom.

Comment: It is probably easier in base R than in ggplot : plot the first graphic (`barplot()`) and then the second `plot()` with the option `add=TRUE` to overlap the graphics. But I'm not sure that is what you are looking for, it can be hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`cowplot`](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/) package to achieve this. Especially the `cowplot::plot_grid()` function allows for many customizations of the output plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = runif(n = 10), y = runif(n = 10)))

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = runif(n = 10), y = runif(n = 10)))

p_combined <- cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = c("A)", "B)"))
```

Comment: Just note that calling `library(cowplot)` will change your default theme setting for ggplot2.

Comment: True, but the theme can be set easily (e.g.  ` + theme_gray()`) during the original creation of `p1` and `p2`.